# How to deploy a javafx app as an image bundle without many dlls in the root folder on windows

Tags: javafx

On https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm and more specifically this image: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/img/bundle_file_struc.png

You can see a windows deployed image bundle with only an executable and a couple of other files in the root folder. When I deploy an app using the following commands (EDIT: using oracle jdk 8), I get many dlls in the root directory (50+):

```
mkdir classes
javac -d classes/ src/helloworld/HelloWorld.java
javapackager -createjar -appclass helloworld.HelloWorld    -srcdir classes/ -outdir out -outfile outjar -v
javapackager -deploy -native image -srcfiles out/outjar.jar -appclass helloworld.HelloWorld -outdir out -outfile test
```

I want to get rid of the dlls because they are confusing users by making the executable hard to find. Is it possible, and how ? This is for deploying a javafx app on windows

Comment: Your issue is not quite clear to me, but I'd generally not refer to documentations about bundling JavaFX from 2013, because especially due to modularization a lot has changed until today.

Comment: Have you tried a different native type (e.g. `exe` or `msi`)? See [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/tools/javapackager.htm#JSWOR719) for the available types.

Comment: @slaw I didn't use exe or msi because I don't want an installer, I want a portable app in a folder

Comment: @Reizo I'm using jdk8 so java9 modularization is not relevant I think